# JavaScript arrays changing background and text on load

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to change the background image on an article and the heading text inside this article on load. These two items need to coincide with one another, so random isn't an option. I'm not looking for it to change at an interval, either, just on load. Has anyone had experience with something like this?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a different background/heading text every time you load the page?

Comment: Changing the DOM when the document is loaded is a straightforward task; what do arrays have to do with your question?

Comment: I need it to select from a list of three variables

Answer (score 0):

It isn't totally clear what you're trying to do from your question and comments, but here's an example of how to store some grouped images and text and dynamically change the DOM using that data when the document is loaded.

```
var backgroundAndText = [
  {background:'http://example.com/image1.jpg', text:'This is text #1.'},
  {background:'http://example.com/image2.jpg', text:'This is text #2.'},
  {background:'http://example.com/image3.jpg', text:'This is text #3.'}
];
var loadNewContent = function(o) {
  document.getElementById('marquee').style.backgroundImage = o.background;
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = o.text;
};
document.body.onload = function() {
  loadNewContent(backgroundAndText[0]);
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify that I want to add the background as a style to the article element. The HTML is `<article id="marquee">
        <aside>
         <h1 id="text"></h1>
        </aside></article>`

Comment: @Adahy: please consider editing your question to include more detailed information - the more specifics you include the better the quality of the answers you will get!

Comment: I think you're on the right track, I want the background to be applied as a style on the #marquee element and the text to be applied to the #text element, and for both to change onload. I think your solution is very close to what I want, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

Comment: If it helps at all, I have a link to the code here http://pastebin.parentnode.org/103954

Comment: I removed the final comma and comment from the "backgroundAndText" definition so that it's valid JavaScript, see my updated answer.